# Java - Scan items as a custom class to another custom class

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

So, I have a custom class that basically works like a 2d array. I have all the ways to access items in it as well as set items in it. I have initialised it to take items of a special type I also made. I want to use scan on a file to put items in that file in the array class I made, but they need to be of the special type I'm looking for.

This is what I have, scanner only seems to allow items to be scanned as ints/strings/etc. . . .

```
map = new ArrayMap<Toon>(rows, columns);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while scan.hasNext() 
{  Toon line = sc.next();
    for (int m = 0; m <= map.getRows(); m++) 
    { for (int n = 0; n <= map.getColumns(); n++)
        { map.setPos(m, n, line);
```

So, basically is there a way to get all the scanned items to be of the type toon? It doesn't necessarily have to happen within the loop for me, as long as its done.

Edit: files looks something like:

`````````````````````
|````````````````````|
|o    ooooo     ooooo|
|ooo    ooooo   oo   |
|oo                  |
|oooooooo  ooooooo   |
|ooo      oooo   oo  |
|ooooooo   oooo  oooo|
|____________________|
`````````````````````

Comment: what do the items look like in the file?

Comment: I editted to add what the files look like

Comment: On the file diagram you posted, do the circles mean "there is a glob of data here in the file representing a `Toon` object" or do they mean "put a toon object at these coordinates"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I haven't figured out a clean way to do this with java, so instead I just looped through the entire file, instantiating each item as a certain toon (each one is its own subclass of toon) and then adding them to the array.